# How to get rid of hair root location artifact

Tags: particles

I have a small sphere on which I place a couple hair particles in the particle editor.

When the hair particles have simple children, the sphere is so small that the appear to be emitted from above the surface:

[image]

Is there a way to fix this artifact?

A reasonable fix would be to emit the hair from a smaller sphere inside my actual sphere, but I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid having the extra emission object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enter the ***Particle Edit Mode***.
[image]

Change the *Particle select and display mode* to ***Point select mode***.
[image]

Uncheck the ***Lenghts*** and ***Root*** boxes in Options panel, then select all the hair particles with *border select tool* (<kbd>B</kbd>) and move them closer to the sphere (<kbd>G</kbd>).
[image]

Here is the result.[image]