# How can I move the roots of hair particles?

Tags: particles, hair

One time I accidentally was able to move the roots of hair with the comb tool but I have never been able to do it now that I need to. How can I move the roots of hair particles?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get rid of hair root location artifact](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27456/how-to-get-rid-of-hair-root-location-artifact)

Comment: @PaulGonet I don't think this is a duplicate. I think this is a case of [Duplicate answer vs duplicate question](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/549/duplicate-answer-vs-duplicate-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncheck the 'Root' option in the left hand tool panel, then re-check it when you want to anchor the roots in place again.
[image]

Note that you can also select and translate points with 'G', as in normal mesh editing. You can enable snapping and use it to put your roots back onto your mesh if needed.